# Status Bar and allerts

Tags: status

How to set Alerts on Status Bar, by Powershell and by javascript and Script Editor ? It's important to set the alert fast for all the organization.

The objective is to communicate system wife status information with all users on all sites quickly. What would be the most effective way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please supply more details about what you are trying to achive? I'm not able to understand your domain at all right now. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to allert important masages for organization by Status Bar in Sharepoint. On all Pages. Like internet is down. By red Skwer like Editing mage without Approve.

Comment: That question, without any details what you have tried, what you can do and what your demands are is too wide a question for this community I'm afraid

Comment: But Only I want to set status bar. On Sharepoint for all sites.

Comment: That is not something you can do easily by just pushing some buttons I'm afraid

Comment: I've read the comments and would propose a different way of solving this problem. You could edit the master page adding a banner to each page and then have the banner source from data in a list elsewhere. Then when you want to send notifications to all users, simply update the banner info list.

Comment: @CorneliusJ.vanDyk I'll reopen the question. But I stand by the view that this question is way to vague and seeking to be a good match for this community

Comment: Robert, I understand your position. Maybe the question can be edited to be more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/01/09/sharepoint-showing-notification-and-status-message-using-sp-js-aspx-2/

If you wrap this in a User Custom Action Scriptlink

http://johnliu.net/blog/2015/12/the-safest-future-proof-way-to-brand-your-sharepoint-and-sharepoint-online

it can execute on every page